# (C++) What is this error about: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linked-list, hashtable

i am making a hashtable using ordered linked lists in C++ to store a list of names.

i keep getting a compilation error on my createhashTable function. i am trying to create a blank table with dummy nodes from 0 -> bucketsize
my code looks like this:

```
class listNode{
    public:
    string firstName, lastName;
    listNode* next;
    
    listNode(){
        firstName = "dummyfirst";
        lastName = "dummylast";
        next = NULL;
    }

    listNode(string firstName, string lastName){
        this->firstName = firstName;
        this->lastName = lastName;
        this->next = NULL;
    }

    void printNode(listNode* node, ofstream* outFile){
        if(node->next == 0) {
            *outFile << "\n";
        }   
        else{ 
            *outFile << "(" << node->firstName << "," << node->lastName << "," << node->next->firstName << ")  --> ";
        }
    }
        
    friend class hashTable;
}; //end of listNode class


class hashtable {
    public:
        char op;
        string firstName, lastName;
        int bucketSize;
        listNode *hashArr;
        

        void createHashTable(int bucketSize){
            /////////////////
            int i = 0;
        //  hashArr = new listNode[bucketSize];

            while(i < bucketSize){
                &hashArr[i] = new listNode[bucketSize];

                i++;
            }
        }
```

i am getting this error:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘void hashtable::createHashTable(int)’:
main.cpp:51:42: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     &hashArr[i] = new listNode[bucketSize];
```

how can i implement this function properly.
^

Comment: What do you expect `&hashArr[i]` to do? This is the address of an object. You can't change the address of an object. You can only change the (value of the) object. What is it that you want to achieve? Maybe `hashArr` must have another type?

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve] with this kind of questions. Even before, just do a simple search online for the error message to start your research. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

As Werner Henze stated, `&hashArr[i]` cannot be modified as it's an rvalue. Nor does such an expression make sense in this context. You are trying to create an array on the heap with a specified size. Remove the address of prefix, i.e. `hashArr[i] = new listNode[bucketSize];`